# Changing the DVD Drive in a Mac Pro

Tags: mac-pro, optical-drive

I have a spare BluRay Drive. I wonder if I can replace the Superdrive in my Mac Pro? I know I could install it along side, but I need the drive very rarely, so I just prefer to replace it.

I'm mainly concerned about the ability to boot and install Mac OS X from it, and about compatiblity with Disk Utility and other burning Software like iLife and DVD Studio Pro. I know that BluRay isn't supported (I dual boot Windows for that purpose)

Comment: (It's the Mid-2010 Single CPU 2.8 GHz Model if it matters)

Comment: Why not just install both? You have two optical drive slots.

Comment: @Cajun I use the optical drive so rarely that I don't see the point in using power and generating noise if I know I'll never need it. Just want to make sure not to run into issues in the future. I'm just trying it now, will see if I encounter software that doesn't work w/o an official SUperdrive.